# Add x amount of new rows with different time interval based on the timestamp and the interval value

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, pyspark

I have the following dataframe:

| Timestamp | Values | Duration | 10MinInterval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2019 08:20:00 | xxx | 00:50:00 | 5 |
| 01-01-2019 09:10:00 | xx | 00:10:00 | 1 |
| 01-01-2019 09:20:00 | xxxxx | 01:10:00 | 7 |
| 01-01-2019 10:30:00 | xxxxxx | 00:40:00 | 4 |
| 01-01-2019 11:10:00 | xx | 01:00:00 | 6 |
| 01-01-2019 12:10:00 | xxxx | xxxx | xxxx |

I would like to add the 10 minute intervals as new rows. For example, the first timestamp has the interval of 5. So I would like to add 5 new rows for 8:30, 8:40, 8:50 and so on, including 09:10. The values in other columns shall stay the same. Any idea how I can do it?

It should look something like this:

| Timestamp | Values | Duration | 10MinInterval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2019 08:20:00 | xxx | 00:50:00 | 5 |
| 01-01-2019 08:30:00 | xxx | 00:10:00 | 1 |
| 01-01-2019 08:40:00 | xxx | 01:10:00 | 7 |
| 01-01-2019 08:50:00 | xxx | 00:40:00 | 4 |
| 01-01-2019 09:00:00 | xxx | 01:00:00 | 6 |
| 01-01-2019 09:10:00 | xxx | xxx | xxx |

Comment: can you share data as dict please

Comment: `df['Timestamp'] = pd.date_range(start='01-01-2019 08:20:00', periods=len(df), freq='10min')`?

Comment: Do you need PySpark answers, or was this tag a mistake?

Comment: both pandas or pyspark would be ok. Just need the solution using python. Unfortunately I dont have dict data only csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PySpark, you probably could use `sequence` with `interval 10 minute`.

**Spark 3.2+**

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('01-01-2019 08:20:00', 'xxx', '00:50:00', 5),
     ('01-01-2019 09:10:00', 'xx', '00:10:00', 1),
     ('01-01-2019 09:20:00', 'xxxxx', '01:10:00', 7),
     ('01-01-2019 10:30:00', 'xxxxxx', '00:40:00', 4),
     ('01-01-2019 11:10:00', 'xx', '01:00:00', 6),
     ('01-01-2019 12:10:00', 'xxxx', None, None)],
    ['Timestamp', 'Values', 'Duration', '10MinInterval'])

df = (df
    .withColumn('time', F.to_timestamp('Timestamp', 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss'))
    .withColumn(
        'Timestamp',
        F.expr("explode(sequence(time, time + make_dt_interval(0, 0, 10 * 10MinInterval), interval 10 minute))"))
    .drop('time')
)
```

Result:

```py
df.show()
# +-------------------+------+--------+-------------+
# |          Timestamp|Values|Duration|10MinInterval|
# +-------------------+------+--------+-------------+
# |2019-01-01 08:20:00|   xxx|00:50:00|            5|
# |2019-01-01 08:30:00|   xxx|00:50:00|            5|
# |2019-01-01 08:40:00|   xxx|00:50:00|            5|
# |2019-01-01 08:50:00|   xxx|00:50:00|            5|
# |2019-01-01 09:00:00|   xxx|00:50:00|            5|
# |2019-01-01 09:10:00|   xxx|00:50:00|            5|
# |2019-01-01 09:10:00|    xx|00:10:00|            1|
# |2019-01-01 09:20:00|    xx|00:10:00|            1|
# |2019-01-01 09:20:00| xxxxx|01:10:00|            7|
# |2019-01-01 09:30:00| xxxxx|01:10:00|            7|
# |2019-01-01 09:40:00| xxxxx|01:10:00|            7|
# |2019-01-01 09:50:00| xxxxx|01:10:00|            7|
# |2019-01-01 10:00:00| xxxxx|01:10:00|            7|
# |2019-01-01 10:10:00| xxxxx|01:10:00|            7|
# |2019-01-01 10:20:00| xxxxx|01:10:00|            7|
# |2019-01-01 10:30:00| xxxxx|01:10:00|            7|
# |2019-01-01 10:30:00|xxxxxx|00:40:00|            4|
# |2019-01-01 10:40:00|xxxxxx|00:40:00|            4|
# |2019-01-01 10:50:00|xxxxxx|00:40:00|            4|
# |2019-01-01 11:00:00|xxxxxx|00:40:00|            4|
# +-------------------+------+--------+-------------+
# only showing top 20 rows
```

**Spark 3.0+**

```py
df = (df
    .withColumn('time', F.to_timestamp('Timestamp', 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss'))
    .withColumn(
        'Timestamp',
        F.expr("explode(sequence(time, time + make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10 * 10MinInterval), interval 10 minute))"))
    .drop('time')
)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I have tried it and I received the following error: "Undefined function: 'make_dt_interval'. Further question is it possible to combine this code with groupBy. For Example having another column like "Names" with the names of different persons and executing this code using groupBy() on the "Names" column.

Comment: `make_dt_interval` is available only from Spark 3.2

Comment: For another question, it seems possible, but it's not trivial. So you will have to create a separate question with example dataframes.

Comment: @AzUser1 - I have added the code for Spark 3.0